# 2008 Chevy Cobalts engine light came on, rpms fluctuates/ stalls, and rpm needle shows zero

Tags: engine, chevrolet, cobalt

My car is a 2008 Chevy Cobalt (standard). I was driving my car the other day and I felt a slight chug, so instinctively I just shifts down a gear and went on my way. The next day it did the same thing, but more violently jerked and chugged so I began to be worried. Later in the week it chugged, and the rpm needle slammed to zero and stopped moving despite my gear shifts, it would reset and start working after shutting the car off for a moment. 
Today it did the same thing, but this time the engine light came on, and the rpms are fluctuating far worse if I slow down, or initially when I shift gears. Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you checked for codes?